# Verifying if CSS is compatible with all browsers

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can find out if CSS I am using works fine with most of the browsers ?
I got some reference http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2009/06/a-harsh-css-environment-for-testing-widgets.html

Comment: Nothing beats manual, human, visual testing.

Comment: What we do is read the HTML header to detect the browser, then use Javascript to render the correct stylesheet for the browser. We started doing this less often since switching to JQuery-UI.

Comment: If you are using Safari or Opera, they have renderers for other browsers built-in.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply test it in most of the browsers, if you so wish. Things like http://browsershots.org or Expression Web SuperPreview can be of great help there.

Comment: I did see something like this but it was a paid thing! And I thought my only option was virtual pc!!

Comment: Browsershots does have a paid option. The free option is painfully slow. Also, of course, it only helps for static content; it won't help at all for any dynamic content.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the *best* way to find out if your code works in all browsers is to actually *run* it in all browsers. But I acknowledge it's not always as simple as that! (especially trying to work out exactly what's happened when you do get problems)

My CSS compatibility Bible are the [Quirksmode.org compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

The author of that site has written a very comprehensive set of tables showing virtually every feature of CSS along with its browser compatibility, including notes about bugs and other odd quirks.

I simply can't recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 4):

Some pointers to good tools or research data, in recommended processing order.

### Clean It

While you're there, you might as well start from a clean slate:

- [CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)
- [CSS Tidy Online](http://csstidyonline.com/)
- [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com/)
- [CSS Formatter and Beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/)

### Validate It

Not always possible in the real world with gory hacks, but still. Good baseline to avoid screw-ups.

- [W3C CSS Validator Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

### Unit-Test It

Not all of them are exactly unit testing tools, but the idea is too checked that the computed style are actually what you expect and that elements are where you expect them to be after styling.

- [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) / [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/)

### User-Test It

Use full-user or semi-user-automated checkers (they run, you check):

- [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)
- [Litmus](http://litmus.com/)
- [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/)

### Compress It

Once it's cleaned and good, you may want to compress it (and redo the steps above with the compressed version):

- [CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/)
- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [CSS Optimizer](http://www.cssoptimiser.com/)

### Research It (and Re-Do It)

*Research* similar questions and tools (until, well, the end of days, and add to this list).

- [CSS Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342579/css-unit-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with adobe browser lab https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html but browsershots is always my first choice

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this list too http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html . Hope this helps