# how to test that the layout of a web app UI is correct. Shall I do it using Karma/Jasmine in Angular

Tags: angular6

My Angular 6 app uses CSS grid. I have placed different components in differents rows and columns. I want to write a test case in which I want to check that a particular component has a specific row and column value.

Eg, say `<nav-component>` component is being used in `app-component`. The css to place `nav-component` at a specific row and column is

```
nav-component {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;

}
```

How can I test that `nav-component` has `grid-column` 1/-1 and `grid-row` 1/2?

So far, I have written

```
fit('Nav Component should be at the top of the page',()=>{
      const fixture:ComponentFixture<AppComponent> = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const appDebugElement:DebugElement = fixture.debugElement; //app-component
      const navChild:DebugElement = appDebugElement.query(By.css('nav-component'))
      console.log('navChild is ',navChild);
      //HERE I WANT TOCHECK THAT NAV HAS A SPECIFIC ROW AND COLUMN VALUE

    });
```

Comment: In general, you don't check styling from unit tests.

Comment: ok. How do you suggest I should check that the UI is fine? Selenium? For knowledge purpose, how could I achieve what I want to do in Angular tests?

Comment: Perhaps check out [this stack overflow question about unit testing css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342579/css-unit-testing) as it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Today, this could be done e.g. via Cypress by comparing snapshots of the application or individual components.

See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing for details.